# How do you pass in props to another component in TabBarIOS?

Tags: json, react-native, state, tabbarios

```
      <TabBarIOS.Item
        icon={{uri: base64Icon, scale: 3}}
        title="Match Facts"
        badge={this.state.notifCount > 0 ? this.state.notifCount : undefined}
        badgeColor="black"
        selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'matchFacts'}
        onPress={() => {
          this.setState({
            selectedTab: 'matchFacts',
          });
        }}>
        <MatchFacts propsToCall={this.props.matchFacts}/>
      </TabBarIOS.Item>
```

==================

MatchFacts component

```
constructor(props) {
super(props)

this.state = {
  selectedTab: 'matchFacts',
  matchInfo: {}
}

  }

  componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({
          matchInfo : this.props.matchFacts
        })

   console.log(this.state.matchInfo)
  }

  componentDidMount(){
console.log('did mount ' + this.state.matchInfo.localteam_name)
  }
```

Inside my TabBar.Item tab, I want to pass in this.props.matchFacts so it can be used in the MatchFacts component. When I pass it in on the line that contains " MatchFacts propsToCall={this.props.matchFacts} " that I thought should theoretically pass in the props to the next component. When I try to access the props in the MatchFacts component it does not work. I believe i'm doing something wrong here in the lines of code I provided..

Comment: It looks fine. I'm assuming this is in the `render()` method? Could you show us how you're trying to access these props in `MatchFacts?`

Comment: Before I even render() the data, I need to set it to the state. I'm having difficultly retrieving the data as I pass the props. In MatchFacts, it currently console logs an empty {}. This is why i'm thinking something might be wrong with how I pass the props via TabBarIOS.

Comment: I figured it out. I ended up using react-native-navbar which is easier to passProps through. Thanks though!